# When using the puppet node init command, are the parameters to specify in the answers.install file

Tags: vmware-esxi, puppet, cloud-computing, vmware-vcenter, puppetmaster

On puppet-enterprise version 3.3.1, I am attempting to use the puppet node init command on a VMware puppet master node hosted on a VMware VSphere client with VCenter 5.1.0. My puppet master node has its permission configuration on another remote VM with postgresql installed.

I am executing the command in order to install puppet-enterprise on a newly provisioned node. Both are Ubuntu 12.04 VMs. I have manually installed a node previously and set it up as a slave node by accepting the certificate via my puppet console. I am currently attempting to set it up via the command puppet node init instead.

Looking through the docs on the ENC (external node classifier), I have not found mention of the node.yaml file as specified. I have tried to fill the parameters using my answers.install file, my puppet master, and my puppet master console, but it seems my particular configurations do not seem to be working? I do not recall assigning any node group, therefore I used the default specified in the answers.install file as 'pe-puppet', but I have also tried to use the group 'mcollective' as it is a group listed on the console group tab.

I have not done any configuration on my newly provisioned vm which I am trying to install puppet-enterprise on other than log in as root and create a password. Ergo, do I need to set up hosts, hostname, etc. or should I be able to do so via the puppet node init parameters? I imagine that it should be the case in which I should be able to set up a puppet VM without having done any previous modifications on a generic empty Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the procedure there: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/quick_start.html#installing-the-puppet-master ?

You must :
- Retrieve the puppet-enterprise tarball on the website, extract its content.

- Then, you must run ./puppet-enterprise-installer
- Ultimately, you need to go to the web administration launcher: https://your.FQDN.master:3000

Following your answers, it will generate an answer file.

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked, but my answer file's parameters were not working. I followed the procedure as specified.